# 18.04 Stuck in login loop, startx fails

Tags: xorg, login

Per other threads I've verified that .Xauthority and .ICEauthoriy belong to my user, that I have free space on disk, and that /tmp is permissioned correctly

```
ls -lA
-rw-------  1 eights eights      51 Feb  8 12:31  .Xauthority
```

```
drwxrwxrwt  13 root root    602112 Feb  8 12:38 tmp
```

I looked at `.xsession-errors` it's just a bunch of setting lines

```
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/eights/.Xauthority
...
```

I can login via SSH and TTY2, I've tried purging all nvidia packages and rebooting (login fails) then re-installing nvidia-384 and rebooting (login still fails).

I looked at Xorg.1.log and didn't see anything interesting (no EE, no WW)

https://pastebin.com/rwapVqqT

`sudo startx` fails but without useful information

```
X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-138-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux eights 4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-45-generic root=UUID=93d06854-e049-4ccd-b9de-bdb2fe89b6ae ro acpi_enforce_resources=lax quiet splash vt.handoff=1
Build Date: 25 October 2018  04:11:27PM
xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Fri Feb  8 12:44:48 2019
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

I've tried installing `lightdm` (and toggling desktop environment between `ubuntu` and `ubuntu with wayland`) both don't work. With gdm3 `unity` works (but I want what I had before). I tried purging and installing ubuntu-desktop but that doesn't fix it either :(

Comment: This isn't a forum! Please do not post a solution in the question itself (or add "solved"). Please remove the edit and **post it as an answer** that you can later accept and **receive points for it**.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out one of my gnome-shell extensions was broken. I had tried `gnome-shell-extensions-tool -d <NAME>` which claims it disabled the extension but I had to move the folder out of the directory to fix it.